# Android application Gradle error

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I an a new at App developing under android studio and I have faced this error with the Gradle:

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Exception in thread \"main\" ","sources":[{}]}

:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I will be grateful for any support.

Comment: every time you get "finished with non-zero exit value" error try cleaning and  rebuilding the project. If that doesn't work, try to "invalidate and restart".

Answer (score 0):

### Change in build gradle

Change your buildToolsVersion
TO

buildToolsVersion "23.3.0"

File Path : GradleScripts/build.gradle(Module:app)

After change sync your project it will work.

Comment: I m sorry it doesn t solve the issue. Let me just note that I got this error when I try to run the app on the emulator.